# resizing images based on distance between 2 objects in the image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have multiple images, each image has 2 objects,but the camera capturing those images has been moving forward and backward, I want to resize all the images so that the distance between the 2 objects can be the same in all the images.
Can it be done in python and opencv.
currently I'm trying to get the ratio between the distances of 2 images, and then resize, but I can't get the right answer 
code:

```
resize_factor = default_dist_bet_objects / current_image_distance
res = cv2.resize(image, fx = resize_facor, fy= resize_factor, 
interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

then i either crop or paste on another image so that all sizes (300,400)

Comment: Do you have a sensor for determining the distance of the camera? Otherwise you need stereo vision to accurately judge the distance

Comment: No I dont have, i only have access to the images. I get the eucledian distance between the 2 objects in that image.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, minimal code to reproduce the problem, the output you're getting, why that output is wrong, and the desired output.

Comment: I can't be certain since I'm not an expert in optics - but are you sure the `resize_factor` is going to be the same for the `fx` and `fy`?

Comment: This question is a little unclear. Are you trying to calculate current_image_distance?